# Firebase - traversing children without knowing the parent?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

[image]

Hi all,

Im just wondering if it's possible to loop through children without knowing the parent node in Firebase. My structure right now is BOOKS/USERID/BOOKID I would love to loop through ALL the books without knowing the USERID or the parent. I'm hoping to do this from a Cloud Function. Is this possible?

Comment: Since you don't know a particular user, does that mean you want to loop over all books of all users? If so, have a look at [listening for lists of data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#read_and_write_lists), and [looping over data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#listen_for_value_events) in the documentation. If you want more concrete help than that, I recommend trying something based on those docs, and updating your question with what you've tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to loop over all books of all users in Node.js:

```
var rootRef = admin.database().ref("books");
return rootRef.once("value", function(booksSnapshot) {
  booksSnapshot.forEach(function(userSnapshot) {
    userSnapshot.forEach(function(bookSnapshot) {
      console.log(bookSnapshot.key, bookSnapshot.val());
    });
  });
  return true; // to flag that we're done
});
```

Comment: So simple! Thanks.